# Array doesn't initialize. Each element contains trash, but not required value

Tags: c

1. First problem: 0 errors, 0 warnings. Sure the code is correct. Tell me what is wrong? (This is part of program.) I can't understand what is wrong. At least it will display `array[3][3] = {{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}}`
2. Second problem: But instead of 'zero's I see clear fields. (I see nothing) But if there is `{{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}}`, I see '1's... Tell me why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
//#define L 3            /* Including the [0]-element */
//#define C 3            /* Including the [0]-element */
#define RANGE 100      /* Set up the range of random values */

int fill_in(int *, int, int); /* Prototype of function */

int main()
{
   int L = 3, C = 3;

   int array[L][C];  // L - Line, C - Column
   int i, j;        // Global variables

   int * aPtr;
   aPtr = &array[L][C];

   srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

   fill_in(aPtr, L - 1, C - 1);

   /* Displaying array (AFTER) */   //  <--- going to make a function, but my first one 
   printf("\nAFTER:\n");            //       doesn't work correctly =(
   for (i = 0; i <= L - 1; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j <= C - 1; j++)
         printf("%2.d ", array[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}

int fill_in( int * aptr, int m, int n)   ///  PROBLEM?  O_о
{
   int arr[m][n];
   int i, j;      // Local variables

   /* Filling array with random values */
   for (i = 0; i <= m - 1; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j <= n - 1; j++)
         arr[i][j] = 1;      //1 + rand()%RANGE;  // If each element == 1, it works! 
   }

   return arr[i][j];
}
```

UPDATE: 
I've solved it! 
Explanations is in comments of the code.
The following code works properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define Lines 2            /* Including the [0]-element */
#define Columns 2            /* Including the [0]-element */
#define RANGE 100      /* Set up the range of random values */

int fill_in(int*, int, int); /* Prototypes of functions */
int display(int*, int, int);

int main()
{
    int L = Lines, C = Columns;
    int array[L][C];  // L - Line, C - Column
    int* aPtr;
    aPtr = &array[0][0];

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));


    fill_in(aPtr, L, C);   /* Filling array with random values. */
    display(aPtr, L, C);   /* Displaying array. */


    return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**   Eureka!  The fact is that pointer of a[0][0] is *ptr[0], and
      the pointer of a[2][2] is *ptr[8] ---> The 8-th element of the array[2][2].

  >>>>   Pointer sees array[][] not as matrix (square), but as a line!
  >>>>   As if to make a line of a square matrix!

*/

int fill_in(int* aptr, int m, int n)        /* Filling array with random values. */
{
   int i;      // Local variables
   int max_number_of_element = ((m+1)*(n+1)-1);

   for (i = 0; i <= max_number_of_element; i++)
      *(aptr + i) = 1 + rand()%RANGE;

   return *aptr;
}


int display(int* aptr, int m, int n)    /* Displaying array. */
{
   int i;
   int count = 1;
   int max_number_of_element = ((m+1)*(n+1)-1);

   for (i = 0; i <= max_number_of_element; i++)
   {
      printf("%2.d  ", *(aptr + i));

      if (count % (n+1) == 0)
         printf("\n");
      count++;
   }
return i;
}
```

Instead of:

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
   for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      aptr[i * n + j] = 1;
```

I've used:

```
for (i = 0; i <= max_number_of_element; i++)   
  *(aptr + i) = 1;
//Pointer sees array[][] not as matrix (square), but as a direct sequence (line).
```

Not sure whether it does anything outside of the array, but the main problem is solved.

P.S.
Let me know if I was wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't do anything with `aptr` in the `fill_in` function. Instead, you fill the local `arr` array. Do this instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        aptr[i * n + j] = 1;
}
```

Furthermore, this:

```
aPtr = &array[L][C];
```

needs to ne

```
aPtr = &array[0][0];
```

You want a pointer to the first element of your array.

Also, instead of `counter <= max - 1`, use the more concise and conventional `counter < max` notation.

Comment: /*What does it mean? Can't understand what it does?*/
    aptr[i * n + j] = 1;  /* Shows only a[0][0] (1) */

/*I tried:*/
aptr[i*j] = 1;   /* Shows a[0][0..2]  (1 1 1)  (this is quite better, than only first element)*/

Comment: @user2186301 Arrays are contiguous in memory. Time to fire up a good guide on arrays and pointers. http://c-faq.com

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
int * aPtr;
aPtr = &array[L][C];
```

You are assigning a pointer to a position out of array bounds. The array is defined from 0-2 on both lines and columns, and you are assigning position (3,3) to the pointer.

Besides this, you are doing nothing with the pointer you pass as argument to the fill_in function.